# Removing LAMP server from ubuntu server edition with tasksel

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, lamp

I have a lamp server running on ubuntu server edition, and I want to uninstall lamp.

`sudo tasksel remove lamp-server` returns `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`.

`sudo tasksel --section server`, then unselecting lamp-server also returns `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`.

`sudo apt-get update`, then either of the previous commands does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get remove lamp-server^ --simulate`

If that looks like what you want, remove the `--simulate` flag and actually do the uninstall.

A variation of that, targeting relevant packages manually, would be along the lines of :
`sudo apt-get --simulate remove mysql-server apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 openssh-server openssl`

If there are other packages that depend on things like `mysql` that you want to keep, that might be a better way to go.  Again, remove `--simulate` to actually run the command.  (With `apt-get`, `-s` is equivalent to `--simulate`, and you would probably use it instead in day-to-day work.)

For the `tasksel` and `aptitude` problem in particular, you might try `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get clean` to see if that clears the error.